# scale several bones envelopes proportionally

Tags: armature, bones

I am looking to proportionally scale down (for example) all bone envelopes in the hand of an armature [image: (multi-select of hand area bones)].

However I cannot seem to use the Deform Distance:

[image]

nor the Scale tool to effect the envelope distance of the multi-select, proportionally.

[image]

Is there a way to do this without resorting to scripting (python)?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It appears the Alt-S and Ctrl-Alt-S work to scale multiple, proportionally.